# cannot launch node head_pointer on pr2_surrogate, Oculus Rift dk1

Tags: ros, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey Guys,

I am trying to use pr2_surrogate with oculus dk1. I get the oculus working with rviz and the kinect rendering to it, but I can't get the robot head to follow the head tracking. After I initialize robot.launch I get the following:

ERROR: cannot launch node of type [pr2_surrogate/head_pointer]: can't locate node [head_pointer] in package [pr2_surrogate]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [pr2_surrogate/arm_mover]: can't locate node [arm_mover] in package [pr2_surrogate]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [pr2_surrogate/arm_mover]: can't locate node [arm_mover] in package [pr2_surrogate]

Any ideias on what it could be?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193849/cannot-launch-node-head_pointer-on-pr2_surrogate,-oculus-rift-dk1/) by [Fred Eduardo](https://answers.ros.org/users/20246/fred-eduardo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2014-09-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-09-30**:
Have you built the pr2_surrogate package?

**Comment by [Fred Eduardo](https://answers.ros.org/users/20246/fred-eduardo/) on 2014-09-30**:
I was using catkin_make on top of ws, figured I had to do make on pr2_surrogate folder for some reason. Sorry, newbie here :)

**Comment by [dido_yf](https://answers.ros.org/users/21158/dido_yf/) on 2014-12-18**:
hello, I have the same problem with you. Did you solve this problem? Could you tell me how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

pr2_surrogate is a rosbuild package, so you should have it in a separate rosbuild workspace.

The [using rosbuild with catkin tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/using_rosbuild_with_catkin) explains the process in more detail.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0